# Method get of Hashtable returns null

Tags: java, hashtable

I am trying to code a sokoban solver, My code works, but it takes so much time to calculate the solution. I think it's because I use ArrayList, I tried to use Hashtable but the method get does not work,

```
Hashtable < Vertix, ArrayList<Vertix>> Graph;
```

so when I fill my hashtable, and use the key to get the list I get null.

```
Graph.get(new Vertix(5,3));
```

however the vertix exists in Graph.

how can I solve this problem to increase the speed of my Sokoban solver.

Comment: There is no general advice on your question, Hashtable and ArrayList are completely different classes and do not share a single interface related to collections. Please provide some more code of your calculations so we can give you better advice on optimizations. And please: follow standard coding conventions and name your variables and fields with a lowercase letter in the beginning. Will help us to understand code snippets better.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Vertix` your own class? If so, it needs to have a definition of equals and hashcode methods to be compared against other instances with *matching values*.

Otherwise, the `new` *reference* you've created doesn't exist in the table.

Also, unless you need thread safety, you can just use Hashmap

Answer (score 1):

You should read the javadocs for `HashMap` and `HashTable` where it explains how lookups are performed, and the requirements on the `hashcode` and `equals` methods.

The most likely explanation for your problem is that your `Vertix` class doe not override `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode`.  Therefore, your class is inheriting *"equality means same object"* behavior from `java.lang.Object`.  In other words, every `Vertix` instance is not equal to every other `Vertix` instance.  Thus

```
    new Vertix(5, 3).equals(new Vertix(5, 3))
```

evaluates to `false`.  That would explain why `Graph.get(new Vertix(5,3))` returns `false`.

---

Solution: override `equals` and `hashCode` so that they have the correct properties for your application.

Reference:

- [Java `equals()` and `hashCode()` Contracts](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)

---

Note that there are some style, etc errors in your code snippets.

- You probably should use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`.  `Hashtable` is *notionally* thread-safe, but this comes at the cost of acquiring and releasing a lock on each `get` and `put`.  If your code is single threaded, this is unnecessary.  Conversely, if your code is multi-threaded, then a `Hashtable` is liable to be a concurrency bottleneck.
- `Graph` is a variable name, so it should start with a lowercase letter.
- `Vertix` is probably a spelling error.  The English word for a node in a graph is "vertex", not "vertix".  ("Vertix" is a trademark for a GPS watch, a multiplayer shooter game, etcetera.)